# How to wait for the next input?

Tags: c#, input, xna, keyboard

I'm trying to implement in my game project in C# a way for the user to change the keys made for moving the character (Up key, Left key, and Right key). I created buttons in my option menu, but I'm still trying to figure out what to put in the event when I click on these buttons. I already looked up in the forum, and didn't find anything really helpful and easy to understand for me ...

I want when I click on the button for defining for example the Up button to wait for the next input the player will make, but I didn't find something yet, something simple.

Can someone please help me ? I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: If I understood you right, your trying to find a way to let the user customize their input but because xna uses [`KeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboardstate.aspx), your unsure of how to achieve this

Comment: Exactly, I'm not sure to know how KeyboardState works.
I tried this :
`KeyboardState newkb = Keyboard.GetState();  
while(newkb.GetPressedKeys() == null)  
{  
   newkb = Keyboard.GetState();  
}  
keysItems[1] = newkb.GetPressedKeys()[0].ToString();`  
But he just jump off the "while" part. What `Keyboard.GetState` does exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like Sayse said, I would use The KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys() method and they will return the keys pressed. I think you can check to see if this is null (untested);

```
while(currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys() == null)
```

Something along those lines you could create a screen (like in battlefield, or CoD) that says "Press key to assign to Forward". Once the user presses a key, you could store the enum. Write the enum to the registry or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested but it seems like it should work in my mind

KeyboardState has a method called [`GetPressedKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboardstate.getpressedkeys.aspx), so all you should need to do is check if your defined keys are contained within this list.

For example, (untested)

```
Key UserDefinedUpKey = Keys.Up;

//UpdateMethod...
var keys = currentKeyboardState.GetPressedKeys();
if(keys.Contains(UserDefinedUpKey))
//Up pressed
```